# Closed memorystream. cannot find the error

Tags: c#, excel, swagger, memorystream, npoi

Please take a look at this:
Controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetExcel(InputSimpleString supplierNo)
{
    var stream = handler.GetExcelOld(supplierNo.input, true);

    if (stream != null)
    {
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "ExternePerformance_" + supplierNo.input + ".xlsx"
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

        return ResponseMessage(result);
    }

    // Handle the case where the stream is null (e.g., file not found)
    return NotFound();
}
```

My Handler:

```
public MemoryStream GetExcelOld(string input, bool fileSaveSelected = false)
{
    string excelFilePath = @"C:\TemplateExcel\Test_template.xlsx";
    string outputFilePath = @"C:\TemplateExcel\Modified_Test_template_LIEFERANTT.xlsx"; // Specify the new file path and name

    IEnumerable<relISSPurchORExtended> allData = new List<relISSPurchORExtended>(); //EMPTY FOR LET THIS EASY HERE
    // Ensure the file exists
    if (File.Exists(excelFilePath))
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
//Here i am reading my excel template, which should be modified in here (not in the file itself)
            using (FileStream readStream = new FileStream(excelFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(readStream); 
                ICellStyle dateTimeStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
                dateTimeStyle.DataFormat = workbook.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                ISheet sheet = workbook.GetSheet("Daten-Lieferant");

                if (sheet != null)
                {
                    int lastRowIndex = 1;
                    foreach (relISSPurchORExtended item in allData)
                    {
                        IRow newRow = sheet.CreateRow(lastRowIndex); // Create a new row
                        int columnIndex = 0;
                        ICell cell = newRow.CreateCell(columnIndex++);
                        //some crazy stuff:D
                        lastRowIndex++;
                    }
                   
                    try
                    {
                        workbook.Write(memoryStream,true);
                        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); => HERE IT GOES OUT TO MY ERROR
                        // Return the generated Excel file as a MemoryStream
                        if (fileSaveSelected)
                        {
                            // Save the workbook to a file
                            using (FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(outputFilePath.Replace("LIEFERANTT", input), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                            {
                                workbook.Write(writeStream);
                            }
                        }
                        return memoryStream;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Data added to the Excel sheet.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sheet 'Daten-Lieferant' not found in the Excel file.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

if I fire up my handler code with true for fileSaveSelected the file will generated correctly(and i make this before writing the code into the memorycache). so the code around for handling the excel part is okay, and there is data in the worksheet.
But I always get error for a closed stream!? ... I cannot return the excel data stream to my controller and get the data to the user....

Used tools:
c#
NPOI for the excel stuff

Tried:
Tried to do the whole coding in the controller itself,same mistake

ErrorCode:
Auf einen geschlossenen Datenstrom kann nicht zugegriffen werden.

Comment: One problem is here: `using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) { /* ... */ return memoryStream; }`  this will cause the `memoryStream` to be disposed as it is returned.  Are you sure that's not what is actually causing the problem?

Comment: Also, what namespace + nuget is `XSSFWorkbook` from?  Is it [`NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook`](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/blob/master/ooxml/XSSF/UserModel/XSSFWorkbook.cs) from https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/?